# Retrieve Drupal user id from CiviCRM Contact id

Tags: civicrm-entity

Is it possible to retrieve Drupal uid from CiviCRM Contact id? Can any one please guide me?

OR

Is it possible to get the Drupal user detail associated to a payment contribution?

Comment: another way is via eg Views and adding a block - it depends what you are trying to do and that is not clear from your question

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted it's not clear what you're asking but based on your wording I'm going to assume you mean via code. You can use the api explorer at https://mysite.org/civicrm/api (replace "mysite" with your actual site) to explore what's available and give you some sample code. Here's how to get the drupal uid given the civi contact id.

[image]

Comment: I was unable to select "CMS User".CiviCRM 5.7.0, Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

On the contact summary page there is a Contact ID/User ID field - the second number is the drupal uid - and links through to the user record.

[image]